# Move to the next mail instead of the previous one when hitting Delete in Claws Mail

Tags: email, keyboard-shortcuts, email-client, claws-mail

#### Background

When I hit <kbd>Delete</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>) in order to delete a selected email, the program selects the previous email (an older one).

#### Question

Is it possible to modify this behaviour so I can delete an email and move to the newer one?

#### Demonstation

1. I'm reading the selected message. After I'm done with it I would like to delete it and move to the one below (the next one, chronologically speaking).

   [image: There are 3 messages sorted in an ascending chronological order. The message in the middle is selected.]
2. Now I hit <kbd>Delete</kbd>. Now the message above (the previous one) is selected.

   [image: There are 3 messages sorted in an ascending chronological order. The message at the top is selected.]
3. Instead of what we see in the second picture, I'd like the Claws Mail to select the next message after hitting <kbd>Delete</kbd>.

   [image: There are 3 messages sorted in an ascending chronological order. The message at the bottom is selected.]

---

**Details**

- I'm using Claws Mail version 3.16.0.
- I'm running FreeBSD 12-CURRENT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Claws Mail 3.13.1 introduced a [*hidden preference*](http://www.claws-mail.org/manual/claws-mail-manual.html#adv_hidden) called `next_on_delete`, designed to let a user control the message selection when deleting emails.

So in order to solve my problem I had to change `next_on_delete=0` to `next_on_delete=1` in `~/.claws-mail/clawsrc`.

There is a tool called [Clawsker](https://www.freshports.org/mail/clawsker/), which is a GUI to modify [hidden preferences](http://www.claws-mail.org/manual/claws-mail-manual.html#adv_hidden).

---

#### References

- [Claws Mail 3.13.1 Open Source Email and News Client Out Now for Linux and Windows (news.softpedia.com)](http://news.softpedia.com/news/claws-mail-3-13-1-open-source-email-and-news-client-out-now-for-linux-and-windows-497954.shtml)
- [The Claws Mail User Manual: Hidden preferences](http://www.claws-mail.org/manual/claws-mail-manual.html#adv_hidden)

Comment: I can not imagine a work flow where the default of "previous on delete" is actually useful.

Comment: YES!! Ehr, I mean, thank you very much. (note that `clawsrc` must be edited while Claws is not running, or it will overwrite the file when you close it)